# select like json value Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table with JSON array data I'd like to search.

```
CREATE TABLE data (id SERIAL, json JSON);

INSERT INTO data (id, json) 
  VALUES (1, '[{"login_name":"kiemthu"},{"login_name":"abc.vh"}]');
```

I want select all row in this table which have value of json column in a below string

```
;#abc.vn;#phattrien;#cds.gg;#
```

';#abc.vn;#phattrien;#cds.gg;#' like '%' + value in json column + '%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can convert json array items into multiple rows:

```
SELECT id, json_array_elements(json) AS items FROM data
```

Then you can query this temporary table to find IDs of wanted records (`||` means string concatenation):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM
    (SELECT id, json_array_elements(json) AS items FROM data) tmp
WHERE 
    ';#abc.vn;#phattrien;#cds.gg;#' LIKE '%' || (tmp.items->>'login_name') || '%'
```

Finally, after you know IDs, just select what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE id IN (    
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM
        (SELECT id, json_array_elements(json) AS items FROM data) tmp
    WHERE 
        ';#abc.vn;#phattrien;#cds.gg;#' LIKE '%' || (tmp.items->>'login_name') || '%'
)
```